# Displaying markers from React Native Maps using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, ecmascript-6

I have this array in my state:

```
coinCoordinatesArray: [
        {
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324},
        {
        latitude: 38.78825,
        longitude: -120.4324},
        {
        latitude: 31.78825,
        longitude: -80.4324},
        {
        latitude: 55.78825,
        longitude: -95.4324}
```

I am trying to render markers using coordinates from the state:

```
            {this.state.coinCoordinatesArray.forEach((coordinate) => {
                        return  (<MapView.Marker
                          onPress={() => alert('fire')}
                          icon={require('./assets/coin_small.png')}
                          coordinate={coordinate}
                          />)
            })}
```

However the markers are not rendered at all but also I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a `forEach()` which just generates the elements, you probably want to do a `map()` instead, so your items are accumulated into an array and rendered.

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` doesn't return anything - use `map` instead:

```
{this.state.coinCoordinatesArray.map((coordinate) => {...})}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `forEach()`, which does not return a new array, you should use `map()`.

So replace:

```
{this.state.coinCoordinatesArray.forEach((coordinate) => { ...
```

With:

```
{this.state.coinCoordinatesArray.map((coordinate) => { ...
```

**Edit:** 
Working example:

https://snack.expo.io/S1kstGNhV

**Output:**

[image: demo image]